# iOS NSURLConnection: How to know that all bytes have been sent?

Tags: ios, networking, afnetworking

I am not interested in any received bytes. I just want to find out if all bytes have already been sent (bonus: plus confirmed with TCP-ACK by the server). This is especially interesting in bad networks and network switching cases.

I would prefer to do it with NSURLConnection / NSURLConnectionDelegate and guess that these classes do not offer it, URLSession(Delegate) will not either.

Unfortunately, so far, I only saw how to see the received bytes.

Does anyone know how to find out about the sent bytes?

Answer (score 0):

`NSURLConnection` has been deprecated. You shouldn't be using it for new development, and should be migrating your existing code away from it.

`URLSession`'s various delegate methods will notify you about progress of your session tasks.

The `URLSessionTaskDelegate` method `urlSession(_:task:didCompleteWithError:)`, for example, notifies you when your task has completed.

The `URLSessionTaskDelegate` method `urlSession(_:task:didSendBodyData:totalBytesSent:totalBytesExpectedToSend:)` will tell you about bytes sent.

The second method seems like it's more informative and closer to what you want.

Comment: Hi Duncan. This might be the best possible answer, but unfortunately it is still quite unsatisfying: 1) it only reports body data, but HTTP/S adds significant overhead that I need to ensure it also sent, 2) it does not address whether bytes are only sent or also TCP-ACK'd, 3) the three possible types of download tasks all come with their shortcoming: Upload is of course the wrong type here, Data does not run in the background, Download sounds like it can only write to a file directly.